# MongoDB group by field for distinct array elements in sub document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-aggregation

I have below document structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("576c5402eef7285c58f6a681"),
    "asOfDate" : 20160602,
    "universe" : [ 
        {
            "memberOf" : [ 
                "group1", 
                "group2", 
                "group3", 
                "group4", 
                "group5"
            ],
            "personName" : "John"
        }, 
        {
            "memberOf" : [ 
                "group22", 
                "group2", 
            ],
            "personName" : "Mary"
        }]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("576c5402eef7285c58f6a684"),
    "asOfDate" : 20160603,
    "universe" : [ 
        {
            "memberOf" : [ 
                "group1", 
                "group2", 
                "group6"
            ],
            "personName" : "Chris"
        }, 
        {
            "memberOf" : [ 
                "group7", 
                "group5", 
            ],
            "personName" : "Jack"
        }]
}
```

I am trying to get a list of distinct `universe.memberOf` for each of the `asOfDates` in the collection. The desired output is below. The only way I could figure out was to run a distinct for each date. But I will have to loop over for each date, which might not be efficient.

```
{ 
    20160602 : ["group1", "group2", "group3", "group4", "group5", "group22"],

    20160603 : ["group1", "group2", "group6", "group7", "group5"]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the aggregation pipeline it could look like so

```
db.getCollection('fooBar').aggregate([
  {
      $unwind: {
         path: "$universe"
      }
  },
  {
      $unwind: {
         path: "$universe.memberOf"
      }
  },
  {
     $group: {
         _id: "$asOfDate",
         memberOf: {
             $addToSet: "$universe.memberOf"
         }
     }
  }
])
```

which will result in

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 20160603,
    "memberOf" : [ 
        "group5", 
        "group7", 
        "group6", 
        "group2", 
        "group1"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 20160602,
    "memberOf" : [ 
        "group22", 
        "group5", 
        "group3", 
        "group1", 
        "group2", 
        "group4"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi DAXaholic. thanks so very much for your solution. This is exactly what I was looking for. Just when you get a chance could you shed some light so as to why do we need to chain the unwind operations? Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. $unwind can only unwind one level at a time so we first have to unwind the universe array and then the memberOf array.